# Make hook local in emacs

Tags: hook, local, emacs24

How do I make this hook local:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook(lambda ()
  (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 80) ))
```

I want it to only effect the current buffer and not new buffers in other modes.

EDIT: found an even better way to narrow the frame to my liking:

```
(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-window-margins (car (get-buffer-window-list (current-buffer) nil t)) 24 24)))
```

This of course is a hook in itself but the question remains the same:

How can I have the margins set to 24 24 when I change to text-mode and have them change back when I switch mode.

Answer (score 3):

Great that a solution was found! For the record, I'll just add that a hook *can* be made *buffer-local* in Emacs. This may not be what the original question [was after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186379/make-hook-local-in-emacs#comment33785272_22228128) since a buffer-local variable applies to a specific buffer - not a specific mode or frame.

Anyway, the Emacs manual states on [Hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html):

> If the hook variable is buffer-local, the buffer-local variable will be used instead of the global variable. However, if the buffer-local variable contains the element `t`, the global hook variable will be run as well.

A hook can be made buffer-local by adding a fourth non-nil argument to `add-hook` as in:

```lisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'the-function-to-add nil t)
```

See also: [Buffer-local after-save-hook?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41023/28441)

Comment: This answer looks good and should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are, per definition, not local. They are designed so that whenever a new buffer is created in text mode (in this case), they run their hook.

In your case, this mean that whenever you create a new text file, your frame will be resized.

If you only want to do this once, you can easily create a command that does this.

```
(defun my-set-frame-width ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 80))
```

You can call this using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `my-set-frame-width` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: Probably local wasn't the right term. What I mean is: I would like the frame to change when I switch to text-mode and then change back to default when I change to a mode that's not text mode. With the above code the frame remains 80 characters wide when I change to another mode. Meanwhile I found that changing margins are better and I would like that to take effect in text-mode and have the margins change back to zero when I switch to other modes.